# Animating RadialGauge

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm new to animations, and I would like to animante `RadialGauge` values changes from **x** to **y**, in order make the transitions smoother.

For example, if the `Value property changes from 0 to 100, I would like the`RadialGauge` to go through all the intermediate values in, for example, 250 ms.

How can I achieve this?

**NOTICE:** I'm using MVVM and I set the `Value` propery via `Binding`. I hope there's a way to do it without adding code-behind (XAML only, preferably).

I'm trying with Implicit Animations, but I don't understand how they work to animate changes in a property. The code that I've tried is this:

```
<controls:RadialGauge Value="{Binding Status.Speed, Converter={StaticResource Speed}}">
    <animations:Implicit.Animations>
        <animations:ScalarAnimation ImplicitTarget="Value" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
    </animations:Implicit.Animations>
</controls:RadialGauge>
```

Comment: did you try Implicit Animations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/implicitanimations

Comment: @Muzib I have investigated about the topic, but I don't know how to achieve it. Please, check the updated question to see the code I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if the Value property changes from 0 to 100, I would like theRadialGauge` to go through all the intermediate values in, for example, 250 ms.

You could use a simple `DoubleAnimation` to achieve your target like the following:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="storyboard" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RadialGaugeControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:3" EnableDependentAnimation="True"></DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <controls:RadialGauge x:Name="RadialGaugeControl"  Value="70" Minimum="0" 
Maximum="180" TickSpacing="20" ScaleWidth="26" Unit="Units" TickBrush="Gainsboro"
ScaleTickBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
NeedleWidth="5" TickLength="18" IsInteractive="True">
    </controls:RadialGauge>
</Grid>
```

```cs
storyboard.Begin();
```

By this way, You need to call `storyboard.Begin();` in code-behind at least.

> I hope there's a way to do it without adding code-behind (XAML only, preferably).

If you check the `RadialGauge` control's [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialGauge/RadialGauge.cs#L500), the value is a dependency property, the needle's angle was changed when the `Value` is changed. What you said 'without adding code-behind', I assumed that you could use some [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki)  to start the animation, but it has not provide any events for you. I did not think it's simpler than calling `storyboard.Begin()`.

You could choose to change the source code and add an animation for it. When the `Value` is changed, the `OnValueChanged` method will be fired, you could start the animation in it. Then, you could compile your custom version for 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls' and use it in your project. But I did not think it's simpler than just writing one line code `storyboard.Begin()` in code-behind.